# Php syntaxes for the_title();

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to make a link to a post:

```
printf('<a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">123</a>', get_the_title($ID), get_permalink());
```

It works, but I need it to display post title and not 123.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can start by reading the help section of this site, in particular the part that deals with _what to ask_, and _what makes a good question_.

Comment: Replace 123 with a variable that stores the title of the post.

Comment: what's wrong with this question? I just asked how to call the_title corectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save your function return values in variables, like this.

```
 $title = get_the_title($ID);
 $link = get_permalink();
 printf('<div><a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a></div>', $title, $link, $title);
```

Comment: Variables are not necessary, it was mainly the `%s` for the link text that was missing. To avoid calling the function that gets the title multiple times, [“argument swapping”](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-4877) technique can be used.

Comment: @CBroe Ya, I know, saved the values in variables just to avoid calling the functions multiple times.

Comment: thx, worked like a charm. If I want to wrap it in a div, how can I do that? (Whole link)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I just edited my answer. <a> wrapped in a div. check now. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
printf('<a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a>', get_the_title($ID), get_permalink(),get_the_title($ID));
```

you can use this